# bootstrap disable white background on <a>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I am using the twitter bootstrap framework. I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid topbar-nav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Whatever</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">My Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`.topbar-nav` is defined as:

```
.topbar-nav {
    background-color: #202020;
}

.topbar-nav a:link { color:#FFFFFF; }
.topbar-nav a:visited { color:#FFFFFF; }
.topbar-nav a:hover { color:#E8E8E8; }
.topbar-nav a:active { color:#B0B0B0; }
```

Whenever I hover over a link, a solid white box appears behind it. It looks like a nice feature but doesn't go with the rest of my design. Is there a way to disable it or change the color? I've looked at bootstrap.css and googled around for a while but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override bootstrap's style for the element's hover event.

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus { background-color:<whatever color you want>; }
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realize it was just the `background-color`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below css:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a:hover{background-color:transparent;}
```